# mysql's createClient function is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have installed mysql using npm intall mysql
I am testing the following code and it is giving an error that 
`TypeError`: `Object #<Object> has no method 'createClient'`

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var client = mysql.createClient({
    user: 'user',
    password: 'abc'
});
client.query('USE databasenm');
```

Please help me in correcting the code

Answer (score 6):

In the docs it says

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
});
```

not `createClient`.

Reference: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: YES) @Alberto

Comment: Woah :D use your password and username, not the one I wrote, I took the example from the library github page

Comment: Now when i place my username and system pasword                    Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'amina'@'localhost' (using password: YES) @Alberto

Comment: You have to configure your database to allow access for the credentials you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Host Name and use createConnection insteat of createClient.
  For further details check this out : https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#install

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#install, you can clearly see that the method is createConnection(...), You should use this. I was also having the same issue. I was reading professional Node.js and in the mysql chapter i encountered this method(maybe it's deprecated with latest versions of node).